# Databinding control properties (e.g. color) to a field which is not displayed

Tags: c#, database, winforms, data-binding, datagridview

I am moving my first steps with databases and databinding, and I'm trying to figure some things out.

In my Access db, I have a table (`Items`) with string fields such as `Description`, `Code` and `Comments`. I also have additional boolean fields such as `Availability` and `Relevance`.

```
"Items"

|  ID  |  Description  |  Code  |  Comments  |  Availability  |  Relevance  |
|      |               |        |            |                |             |    
|   1  |  Apple        |  AP    |  Red       |        x       |             |
|   2  |  Orange       |  OR    |  Orange    |        x       |       x     |
|   3  |  Banana       |  BN    |  Yellow    |                |       x     |
|   4  |  Lime         |  LM    |  Green     |        x       |             |
```

I want to display some of this data in a `dataGridView` via databinding: mostly `Description`, `Code` and `Comments`.

```
private void DataBindGridView()
    {
        string dbPath = @"C:\FruitDB.accdb";
        string connStr = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + dbPath + ";Persist Security Info=False;";

        OleDbConnection dbConn = new OleDbConnection(connStr);
        dbConn.Open();

        string query = "SELECT Description, Code, Comments, FROM Items ORDER BY ID ASC";
        OleDbCommand getItems = new OleDbCommand(query);
        OleDbDataAdapter dbDataAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(getItems);

        DataTable itemsTable = new DataTable();
        itemsTable.Locale = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
        dbDataAdapter.SelectCommand.Connection = dbConn;
        dbDataAdapter.Fill(itemsTable);

        // I want my first column to contain a checkbox for other purposes
        // 
        DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn col1 = new DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn(false);
        col1.Name = "Selection";
        col1.HeaderText = "";
        dataGridView1.Columns.Add(col1);

        // Binding the dataGridView
        //
        dataGridView1.ReadOnly = false;
        dataGridView1.DataSource = itemsTable;

        // The user is allowed to edit the checkbox column only
        // 
        foreach (DataGridViewColumn col in dataGridView1.Columns)
        {
            if (col.Index == 0)
            {
                col.ReadOnly = false;
            }
            else
            {
                col.ReadOnly = true;
            }
        }
    }
```

Now, even though I don't want to display the `Availability` or `Relevance` information as separate columns in the `dataGridView`, I do want that information to be shown in some other way, e.g. as a strikethrough font or by setting the line color to grey.

How do I databind these properties? Do I need to repeat the whole thing with a different another query / command / dataTable...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want something like this:

```
private void dataGridView_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
{
    if (dataGridView.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name == "Availability")
        e.CellStyle.ForeColor = Color.Silver;
}
```

This is basically painting all cells' text in the `Availability` column gray. You can extend the code, it's just to demonstrate the idea.

Also: of course, you should definitely include extra columns in your SQL. Use the `DataGridView` to control how these look like. You can also hide the columns altogether.

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick! I bound all columns from my db table, then set `column.Visible = false` for the ones i didn't want to display, and then used the cellFormatting event.